# Rails works fine locally but not in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have created a custom page for root and changed accordingly in routes.rb.I have removed the public/index.html file before using git but the app still looks for public/index.html file in heroku.The app works fine locally but the problem is while deploying in heroku.Please suggest some solutions?My Gemfile contains

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
end
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails','3.2.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'thin'
```

and i am not using databases in my app.The controller just do some calculations on a json string.

Comment: did you commit your changes to git before pushing to heroku? did you edit your routes.rb and set a 'root :to => "something" ' ?

Comment: yes i did but still i get 500 error

Comment: Heroku log shows this error at=info method=GET path=/ host=guarded-atoll-1158.herokuapp.com fwd=117.204.119.60 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=7ms service=1583ms status=500 bytes=643

Comment: please post the output of "heroku logs" in your projects folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you have used:

```
git add .
git commit -m "blabla"
```

However, `git add .` don't look for deleted files, so the `public/index.html` is still there.

You must use `git add -u` to include the removed files.

Or, you can use `git add -A`, which is is equivalent to `git add .` plus `git add -u`.

**edit** - step by step with comments:

```
git add -A                #add everything (including deleted files)
git commit -m "blabla"    #commit it
git push                  #push from your pc to your git repository
git push heroku           #push from your git repository to heroku
```

If you have deleted the `public/index.html` file it must work.

**EDIT** add the following to your gemfile:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Than:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
git add -A
git commit -m "blabla"
git push
git push heroku
```

Comment: i have edited my answer including a step by step... i hope it helps

Comment: Heroku log shows this error                                     at=info method=GET path=/ host=guarded-atoll-1158.herokuapp.com fwd=117.204.119.60 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=7ms service=1583ms status=500 bytes=643

Comment: I thing the problem is in your assets. Try to run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`, than the steps in my answers, and finally `heroku rake db:migrate`.

Comment: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
rake aborted!
Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)

Comment: can you edit the question to include your `gemfile`? it is probably missing the `gem 'pg'` inside the production group.

Comment: i anm not using any database in my app

Comment: ok,, but you need to precompile the assets. If it do not work after it, please include the logs in the question, by `heroku logs`